# MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk, amazon-sagemaker

I'm working on a supervised machine learning problem, and I am setting up a custom labeling task to send out to Amazon Mechanical Turk for human annotation.

I have uploaded the data to AWS S3 in the json-lines (`.jsonl`) format as follows, pursuant to the instructions as specified in the AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-input.html:

```
{"source": "value0"}
{"source": "value1"}    
{"source": "value2"}
...
{"source": "value2"}
```

When I click on the default text classification template, I can see my data come through and everything appears to work.

However, I am getting the following error when I attempt to use the custom annotation task template interface: `MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params`

The error resembles an AWS Lambda error, except the strange thing is that I am not using AWS Lambda. Suggestions for how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am from the engineering team and happy to help you here. I think the issue is not related to the manifest as it looks correct to me. The error suggests that you may haven't provided a correct lambda ARN for pre or post labeling task. Please see this doc for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-custom-templates-step3.html

I can also help further if you can send me details on how you starting the job and what parameters you are sending.

Comment: A more transparent error function would be really helpful.